# Workflow for datastax PHP Driver installation on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, database, cassandra, driver, datastax

What workflow and procedure have I to follow in order to install the following dependency?
https://github.com/datastax/php-driver

I am trying 2 days now find a way but I can't figure out what code and libraries will I use to integrate PHP and cassandra.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in case you did not notice it, there are detailed instructions on how to install the required dependencies in the very same page
[here](https://github.com/datastax/php-driver/blob/master/ext/README.md).

In my case that just worked (I was running Ubuntu 14.04). I had some issues with one of the libraries I had to download and install manually, but other than that it was pretty straightforward. Hope it helps.

Comment: I have already try it before proceeding in writing here. Is there any way to use the extension ready compiled?

Comment: I think It would have been reported if available as option. Which stage of the installation process gives you issues?

Comment: I think that it is installed but nothing happens in my index.php file when I use php_info(). Nothing is shown about the driver. Why using a ready compiled .so is a fault?

Comment: I am not a PHP expert, anyway having a little more detail about how you executed the script, configurations etc. could help. Since it seems like you do not receive any explicit error, have you tried writing something on Cassandra and checking it back using cqlsh?

Comment: Yes riccamini .. Cassandra works great. But I have problem in compiling the driver. It's very complicated. Honestly I don't understand